# Three variables partial derivatives using chain rule

Tags: partial-derivative

**Question**:

Suppose $w=F(x,y,t), \ y=g(x,t), \ x=h(t)$. Find $dw/dt$ in terms of partial derivatives of $F,g$, and the derivative of $h$.

So I know that I need to use chain rule. But $w$ is a function of $x,y,t$ and when I do partial derivatives, wouldn't there be $dw/dt$ on both sides of equation?

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that, if you write $w$ as $w = F\left(h(t), g(h(t),t), t\right) = F(A_1,A_2,A_3)$, then:

$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} =  \frac{\partial w}{\partial A_1} \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial w}{\partial A_2} \frac{\partial A_2}{\partial t}   + \frac{\partial w}{\partial A_3} \frac{\partial A_3}{\partial t}$$

Note now that:

\begin{align}
\partial_t A_1 & = h'(t),  \\
\partial_t A_2 & = \partial_t g(h(t),t) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial h} \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial t} , \\
\partial_t A_3 & = 1 . \\
\end{align}

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am just thinking, on both sides there are the partial derivatives of w on t, as A3=t, and it would be offset.